# How to load predefined setting in to angular to access setting data through out the application in Ionic 2?

Tags: configuration, ionic-framework, angular, configuration-management

I'm developing an mobile application (Ionic 2 / Angular 2 / TypeScript / webpack) which connects to a server.
I have a production and a stage server and i want to load configuration from a file maybe a js or json so that i can easily have different configuration for different environment.

Reference : https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-platform-web-client/issues/41

Please suggest me a way to this and best practices. Thanks :)

Comment: Any update on this? Did you found a way?

Comment: Hi, yeah I'll answer it soon